# failed to Inject Activiti framework services in my Spring webapp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, activiti

I'm trying to create a workflow in my web application using the frameworks Activiti and Spring MVC, so I have to Inject Activiti Services by the applicationContext.xml file and then autowire these services.

and this is the problem in the consol after a JUnit Test

> GRAVE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener
>   [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@14c8743]
>   to prepare test instance [tds_erp.testSpring@144719c]
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'tds_erp.testSpring': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: org.activiti.engine.RepositoryService
>   tds_erp.testSpring.repositoryService; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [org.activiti.engine.RepositoryService] found
>   for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Could not autowire field: org.activiti.engine.RepositoryService
>   tds_erp.testSpring.repositoryService; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [org.activiti.engine.RepositoryService] found
>   for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>
> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [org.activiti.engine.RepositoryService] found
>   for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

applicatioContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        ">


    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
        <property name="targetDataSource">
            <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
                <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
                <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/activiti" />
                <property name="username" value="root" />
                <property name="password" value="admin" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
        <property name="databaseType" value="h2" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />
        <property name="deploymentResources"
            value="classpath*:chapter4/bookorder.spring.bpmn20.xml" />
        <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="false" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="processEngine" class="org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="processEngineConfiguration" ref="processEngineConfiguration" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="repositoryService" factory-bean="processEngine"
        factory-method="getRepositoryService" />
    <bean id="runtimeService" factory-bean="processEngine"
        factory-method="getRuntimeService" />
    <bean id="taskService" factory-bean="processEngine"
        factory-method="getTaskService" />
    <bean id="historyService" factory-bean="processEngine"
        factory-method="getHistoryService" />
    <bean id="managementService" factory-bean="processEngine"
        factory-method="getManagementService" />
</beans>
```

the JUnit Test file:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.activiti.bpmn.model.Task;
import org.activiti.engine.FormService;
import org.activiti.engine.HistoryService;
import org.activiti.engine.IdentityService;
import org.activiti.engine.ManagementService;
import org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngine;
import org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngineConfiguration;
import org.activiti.engine.RepositoryService;
import org.activiti.engine.RuntimeService;
import org.activiti.engine.TaskService;
import org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath*:applicatioContext.xml")

public class testSpring {

    @Autowired(required=true)
     RepositoryService repositoryService;
    @Autowired(required=true)
     RuntimeService runtimeService;
    @Autowired(required=true)
     TaskService taskService;


    @Test
    public void simpleSpringTest() {

    Map<String, Object> variableMap =
    new HashMap<String, Object>();
    variableMap.put("object", "Activiti in Action");
    variableMap.put("description", "123456");
    runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(
    "employeeRequest", variableMap);

    Task task = (Task) taskService
    .createTaskQuery().taskAssignee("kermit")
    .singleResult();
    assertEquals("Complete order", task.getName());
    taskService.complete(task.getId());
    assertEquals(0, runtimeService.
    createProcessInstanceQuery().count());
    }
    }
```

help me please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to use beans defined in `applicatioContext.xml` like `repositoryService` etc in your test case. But all you are declaring in `the @ContextConfiguration` is the activiti's default config file `activiti.cfg.xml`
Can you try the below in your test:

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:applicatioContext.xml")
```

Just a suggestion: it may be a good idea to create a separate `applicatioContext.xml` for test context similar to the one in webapplicationContext. This will help keep a different data etc where you can manage pre/post conditions of data better than your normal development DB instance. You may even want to spawn a DB instance for the test itself and tear down after the test.

Edits:
You can give multiple conf files like this - `@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicatioContext.xml" , "classpath*:activiti.cfg.xml"})`. check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377699/spring-contextconfiguration-how-to-put-the-right-location-for-the-xml).

generally defining "`<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">`" should load the `activiti.cfg.xml` internally unless you have changed its default location.

Comment: thanx for answer, but i have 2 configuration files, `applicatioContext.xml` and `activiti.cfg.xml` and i tried them but the same problem

Comment: i tried your suggestion, but i dont know how can i call the activiti config after the separation from the applicationContext. it says there is no bean defined

Comment: you can give multiple conf files like this - @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicatioContext.xml" , "classpath*:activiti.cfg.xml"}). check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377699/spring-contextconfiguration-how-to-put-the-right-location-for-the-xml

Comment: generally defining "`<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">`" should load the activiti.cfg.xml internally unless you have changed its default location

Comment: thank you for your answer, its resolved by placing this line `<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">` at the first of the Activiti configuration, so i understand that the ProcessEngine should be loaded as the first one, order is important

Comment: I am glad it worked. From what I know the order of bean definition should not matter. i think it was something else that caused the problem. But i cant say what with limited information of what you fixed :) . But happy to help.

Comment: I have edited the answer from comments. can you accept the answer?