# could not auto wire activiti RuntimeService

Tags: java, autowired, activiti

i am learning to use activiti with spring boot 
but i get some errors and searching too much about acitiviti stable version with spring boot and java

i am using java 8 and tomcat 8.0.3

i changed so many version of spring and jdk and checked so many sample and can not find any problem 
i only have a controller class and spring main class
 when i run the project get this error:

```
 Error creating bean with name 'runtimeServiceBean' defined in class path resource [org/activiti/spring/boot/JpaProcessEngineAutoConfiguration$JpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngine]: : Error creating bean with name 'processEngine'defined in class path resource [org/activiti/spring/boot/JpaProcessEngineAutoConfiguration$JpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration]
```

this is my RestController and do nothing but an autowire

```
       import org.activiti.engine.RuntimeService;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MyRestController {
    @Autowired
    private RuntimeService runtimeService;
}
```

this is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <activiti.version>5.19.0.2</activiti.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic</artifactId>
            <version>${activiti.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-rest-api</artifactId>
            <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-rest-api</artifactId>-->
            <version>${activiti.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${activiti.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Have you configuration class or xml where beans?

Comment: Please post your `RuntimeService` class.

Comment: @AnatolyUtkin no

Comment: @SudhirOjha its in activiti by default

Comment: Lets have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29502838/failed-to-inject-activiti-framework-services-in-my-spring-webapp

Comment: @SudhirOjha i dont have any config class and bean

Comment: first: is there any specific reason to use `activiti 5.19.0.2`, consider upgrading to `activiti 5.22`. second: how do initialize your `Process Engine`, do you let spring handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Activiti with Spring Boot 2.x we recommend to use the new release of Activiti Core 7 which can be found here: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.activiti/activiti-spring-boot-starter/7.0.0.SR1/jar

You can find examples here:
https://github.com/activiti/activiti-examples

Answer (score 0):

after so many search i realized that spring boot 2 have problem with activiti then i change spring boot to version 1.5 
and then i get new error :

```
'formDataResource': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'formService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'formServiceBean' defined in class path resource [org/activiti/spring/boot/JpaProcessEngineAutoConfiguration$JpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'formServiceBean' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngine' defined in class path resource [org/activiti/spring/boot/JpaProcessEngineAutoConfiguration$JpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'processEngine' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springProcessEngineConfiguration' defined in class path resource [org/activiti/spring/boot/JpaProcessEngineAutoConfiguration$JpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration]
```

and the cause of new error : i dont have any process in src/main/resources/processes/

set some process and delete target folder

it worked for me !

Answer (score 0):

With Spring Boot 2.x you have to add the dependence above, and delete the other one.`

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0.SR1</version>
    </dependency>`
```