# How do I configure a controller bean?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

If we have a look at the [Mkyong tutorial for a simple Hello World MVC application.](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/)

Now lets say instead of returning a straight hello, the controller instead calls a business logic layer to get what it wants.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HelloController {


    private BusinessLogic myBusinessLogic; 

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        String text = myBusinessLogic.getMessage();

        model.addAttribute("message", text);
        return "hello";

    }

}
```

I have two questions here.

1. How do I instantiate `myBusinessLogic`? In the exampke mkyong has given, there's no bean configuring the `HelloController`.
2. How do I configure the bean's scope?

Comment: You can autowire your service bean here business logic bean in the controller. You can use this for referance : www.journaldev.com/3531/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-integration-crud-example-tutorial

Comment: @DipenAdroja - The problem I have with this solution, is that I then have this problem for my unit tests. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377699/spring-contextconfiguration-how-to-put-the-right-location-for-the-xml