# Spring MVC Test setup fails on loading ApplicationContext.xml

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test

Currently I'm trying to setup Spring MVC Controller testing for a school project I'm working on next to my job. Normally I program in php and frameworks like Laravel so this is pretty new for me. The problem is that I can't figure out how to solve the problem that keeps popping up on loading the ApplicationContext. Any help is appreciated.

**Update:**

*I'm now told that test cases don't use a jndi ref in my app server. So this reference would fail on a test case, it runs fine on starting the application. Now I made a second file called `servlet-test.xml (listed below)` that uses a reference to the database on port 3306. I only use this file on tests not when starting up the application. But when I use this method I get   `Following error: Error creating bean with name 'productController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed`. Any help is welcome as I'm struggling to setup MVC Controller tests for my school project. Other students I've been working with also are stuck with the same problem I am so I could help them out too.*

**I suspect the problem is the following, but I'm not sure how to solve this.**

```
Error creating bean with name 'myDataSource' defined in URL 
[file:web/WEB-INF/servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for
'java:app/fotoproducent' ...
```

**The Error Stack Trace**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:web/WEB-INF/servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myDataSource' defined in URL [file:web/WEB-INF/servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:app/fotoproducent' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Invocation exception: Got null ComponentInvocation ]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:121)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:250)
at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
```

The Controller test i'm trying to run:

**ProductController Test**

```
package controller.tests.config;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultMatcher;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.DefaultMockMvcBuilder;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"file:web/WEB-INF/servlet-test.xml", "file:web/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml"})

public class ProductControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        DefaultMockMvcBuilder builder = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac);
        this.mockMvc = builder.build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testProductAction() throws Exception {
       ResultMatcher ok = MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk();
       ResultMatcher msg = MockMvcResultMatchers.model()
                       .attribute("msg", "Spring quick start!!");

       MockHttpServletRequestBuilder builder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/product");
       this.mockMvc.perform(builder)
               .andExpect(ok)
               .andExpect(msg);
    }

}
```

**servlet.xml / applicationContext.xml file**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<!-- module/package declarations -->
<context:component-scan base-package="Application" />
<context:component-scan base-package="Authentication" />
<context:component-scan base-package="Photo" /> 
<context:component-scan base-package="Product" />
<context:component-scan base-package="Organisation" />
<context:component-scan base-package="Login" />
<context:component-scan base-package="UI" />
<context:component-scan base-package="I18n" />
<context:component-scan base-package="Internationalization" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" scope="singleton"> 
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:app/fotoproducent" /> 
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true" /> 
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />        
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="*" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>

<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

**Dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMap ping"/>

<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.html">indexController</prop>
            <prop key="test.html">testController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />

<!--
The test controller.
-->
<bean name="testController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="test" />


</beans>
```

**Update 1: "DataSource Configuration"**

This shows how the datasource is configured.

**glassfish-resources.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
<jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="mysql_fotoproducent_rootPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
    <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="portNumber" value="3306"/>
    <property name="databaseName" value="fotoproducent"/>
    <property name="User" value="root"/>
    <property name="Password" value="password"/>
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fotoproducent?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
<jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="app/fotoproducent" object-type="user" pool-name="mysql_fotoproducent_rootPool"/>
</resources>
```

**Update 2: Additional Bean Config file (servlet-test.xml)**

This results in beans not being loaded. Following error: Error creating bean with name 'productController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- module/package declarations -->
<context:component-scan base-package="Application" />
<context:component-scan base-package="Authentication" />
<context:component-scan base-package="Photo" /> 
<context:component-scan base-package="Product" />
<context:component-scan base-package="Organisation" />
<context:component-scan base-package="Login" />
<context:component-scan base-package="UI" />
<context:component-scan base-package="I18n" />
<context:component-scan base-package="Internationalization" />


 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fotoproducent?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />        
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="*" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>

<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


</beans>
```

**Update 3: Additional Code for problem resolving**

**Product Controller**

```
package Product.Controller;

import Product.Sevice.ProductService;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/product")
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    protected ProductService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String productAction(ModelMap model)
    {
        model.put("productList", this.service.findAll());

        return "product/overview";
    }
}
```

**Product Service**

```
package Product.Sevice;

import Product.Entity.Product;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ProductService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public void insert(Product product)
    {
        // insert into database
        // persist function is for NEW entities in database
        this.em.persist(product);
    }

    @Transactional
    public Product get(Integer id)
    {
        // this gets the entity from the database and returns it
        return this.em.find(Product.class, (long) id);
    }


    @Transactional
    public Product update(Product product)
    {
        // this updates the ExampleEntity in within the database
        return this.em.merge(product);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void remove(Integer id)
    {
        Product product = this.em.find(Product.class, (long) id);
        product.delete();

        // this updates the product in within the database
        this.update(product);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Product> findAll()
    {
        Query q = this.em.createNamedQuery("product.namedquery", Product.class);
        return q.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Comment: how have you configured your datasource in your container? can you add that here

Comment: @kuhajeyan I configured the data source in persistence.xml or glassfish-resources.xml, not 100% sure (updated the question).

Comment: there should be datasource that you have configured in container example glassfish, tomcat etc. your  <property name="jndiName" value="java:app/fotoproducent" />  point to that

Comment: @kuhajeyan something like this? This is from glassfish-resources.xml: `<jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="java:app/fotoproducent" object-type="user" pool-name="mysql_fotoproducent_rootPool"/>` The rest is just in `servlet.xml`

Comment: in your glass fish server probably http://localhost:4848 , you should find that. http://javaeesquad.github.io/tutorials/glassfishDatasource/glassFishDatasource.html

Comment: change it to <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="app/fotoproducent" object-type="user" pool-name="mysql_fotoproducent_rootPool"/> and restart glassfish

and change bean property to
<property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/app/fotoproducent" />

Comment: @kuhajeyan if i change the resource and bean mapping i can't run the application anymore. Than i get: `Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource`. Else i can still run the application and only the test will fail.

Comment: If this is a jndi ref then in your app server the jndi should have been defined and test cases don't use app server. That can be the scenario here.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj if this would be the case. Is there any solution you could suggest that i can implement?

Comment: Sure. Define another spring bean xml that is included while running test cases only. In this xml just define the DataSource with same bean id ie myDataSource. In this bean definition do not use jndi rather define database connection using jobs props like URL, username password. It should run fine then.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj Thanks, i will give it a shot. I will post my results here.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj I updated my question. When i try to load in database connection directly i get error `Following error: Error creating bean with name 'productController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed`. Any ideas?

Comment: Paste code for productcontroller and other referenced beans inside this class.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj updated the question it's listed under update 3.

Comment: Your controller doesn't need entitymanager remove that. Secondly can you also share the code of the test case you are trying to execute.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj Alright. Test case is listed under ProductController Test. Method i'm testing is `public void testProductAction()`

Comment: That code should have been updated to include test xml file too

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj updated. Class `ProductControllerTest` now is referring to `servlet-text.xml`

Comment: is your test case failing or entire project is not building up to deploy...??

Comment: @ramesh027 ApplicationContext.xml only works on start of the project. But fails when loading ProductControllerTest while project is running.

Comment: is your application is woking fine apart from the test case...??

Comment: @ramesh027 Yes that is the case it fails to load the beans from servlet-web.xml so test case fails.  App is fine for the rest.

Comment: while writing the junit test case, we should not use the datasource as we are not testing the database connectivity and these test case are unit testcase not integration test case if so then we should use mocking/stubbing framework.

Comment: what version are you using for  spring jdbc template and spring test jar verison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your stack trace when application context is initializing it still try to load wrong configuration files (servlet.xml), but should load servlet-test.xml. Please try to change your config locations with using path from root (src) folder, such as:

```
@ContextConfiguration({"file:src/main/web/WEB-INF/servlet-test.xml", "file:src/main/web/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml"})
```

P.S Also you can try to move your config for tests (servlet-test.xml) to src/test/resources and load it from classpath: "classpath:servlet-test.xml". Also you can check this thread on stackoverflow: [Spring @ContextConfiguration how to put the right location for the xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377699/spring-contextconfiguration-how-to-put-the-right-location-for-the-xml) for extended discussion of similar problem.

Comment: Moved the two files to a different location. And every problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error which says that Spring IOC container fails to create and instantiate `entityManagerFactory` bean. Why?

That's another thing that your error exception mention. It fails to do so because it can't instantiate the `myDataSource` bean. Why?

According to your error message:

```
 Lookup failed for 'java:app/fotoproducent'
```

It means that when IOC Spring container tried to create `myDataSource` bean, it failed to do so because it failed to set the jndiName with value of `java:app/fotoproducent`

Instead of using this:

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" scope="singleton"> 
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:app/fotoproducent" /> 
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true" /> 
</bean>
```

Replace it with:

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="your_driver_class_name" />
    <property name="url" value="url_to_your_db" />
    <property name="username" value="user_name_to_db" />
    <property name="password" value="password_to_db" />
</bean>
```

My suggestion is to create a standard dataSource like mentioned on Spring docs above.

Now don't forget to replace the values for driver class name, url, user name, and password.

Here is an example from Spring docs, of how to define a data source for use of Hibernate ORM: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#orm-hibernate