# No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping]

Tags: spring, cucumber, swagger

I have a spring boot application with swagger configured. I am getting error running cucumber tests. Here are the configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
public class SwaggerConfig {  
}

@Category(IntegrationTest.class)
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:cucumber-spring-beans.xml")
@CucumberOptions(snippets = SnippetType.CAMELCASE, strict = true, monochrome = true, tags = {"~@ManualTest", "~@SlowTest", "~@IgnoreTest", "~@AdHoc", "@IntegrationTest"}, 
features = {CucumberRunnerUtil.CukeFormat.FEATURE_FILE_LOCATION},
plugin = {"pretty", CucumberRunnerUtil.CukeFormat.CD_HTML_REPORT_INTEGRATION, 
        CucumberRunnerUtil.CukeFormat.CD_JSON_RESULTS_INTEGRATION + "integration-test-reports.json",
        CucumberRunnerUtil.CukeFormat.CD_JUNIT_XML_REPORT_INTEGRATION + "integration-test-reports.xml"})
public class RunIntegrationCukeTest {



}
```

**cucumber-spring-beans.xml:**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.samples.mvc" />
<context:annotation-config/>

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com...." >
        <context:exclude-filter type="assignable" expression="com...."/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com...." >

    </context:component-scan>
```

Comment: This link- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377699/spring-contextconfiguration-how-to-put-the-right-location-for-the-xml has most of answers; let's have a try on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excluding the swagger related Java config classes from cucumber-spring-beans.xml did the trick:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="...webservice.resource" >
        <context:exclude-filter type="assignable" expression="...webservice.resource.Application"/>
        <context:exclude-filter type="assignable" expression="...webservice.resource.SwaggerConfig"/>
        <context:exclude-filter type="assignable" expression="...webservice.resource.JerseyConfig"/>
        <context:exclude-filter type="assignable" expression="...webservice.resource.CombinedResourceProvider"/>    
    </context:component-scan>
```